# Sci fi story about an AI trained in empathy, and then released into the universe to find humanity

Tags: story-identification, books

So I remember listening to this one as an audio book years back. It started with a police woman, a mother to at least one kid, stopping a robbery or similar at the cost of her life. After she "died" she was informed that she was in fact an AI who had gone through many such "lives" (to teach her empathy etc I believe). She was then informed by the caretaker AI (possibly called Mother or similar) that the facility was under attack and she had to leave. Turns out she had lived her whole "life" in a deep space base. My memory is foggy after this, but I remember it ended with her and others finding the last remains of humanity frozen in a ship tumbling through space. Then there was a battle of some sort and it ended on a cliffhanger I think. Sorry for the vague description, but it's all I can remember. =)

Answer (score -1):

Sounds a bit like the Post Human series by David Simpson, specifically book 4 "Human Plus".

Doesn't appear to be what you're thinking of but you might like it.

Comment: [*Post-Human* review](https://greggborodaty.com/book-review-post-human-omnibus-edition/). Agreed that it doesn't seem to be a match.

Comment: I haven't read the books, admittedly, just looked at reviews, so if this is a better match than your answer indicates, you may want to [edit] more details in.

Comment: Hm, probably not that one. Felt like the first book in a series to me. Thanks though, may check that out =)